# Suppose $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$. Then is $a^n+b^n+c^n$ divisible by $a+b+c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility, factoring

I tried some examples and they all worked, but I have no idea how to factorize $a^n+b^n+c^n$ into the product of $a+b+c$ and something else.

Could anyone tell me whether this result is true or not? And, if it is true, how to prove it?

Comment: What examples did you try?

Comment: What about $(3,5,7)$? Then $3^2+5^2+7^2=83$ is prime so the statement doesn’t hold

Comment: try $(a,b,c,n) = (3,4,5,2).$

Comment: on the other hand, if both $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$  and $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ are divisible by $a+b+c,$  so are the sums with higher exponents

Comment: thanks guys, it is me that made a snap judgement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s a well-known [classical] recursion:

$a^n+b^n+c^n = (a+b+c)(a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}+c^{n-1})-(ab+ac+bc)(a^{n-2}+b^{n-2}+c^{n-2})+abc(a^{n-3}+b^{n-3}+c^{n-3}).$

I don’t believe there’s any factorization with only $a+b+c$.

Comment: oh yes... haha thanks a lot